# Sharepoint - lookup option, but with text instead of dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have one question regarding sharepoint. I created a lookup value, that goes into a list and looks up different collumns.
The problem is that there are way too many options (I have over 2000 codes in the lookup funciont). 
At the moment, I only have a drop down function, which takes me a lot of time to go through until I find the correct option.
Can you tell me if there is any option for me to just write my option, instead of having a drop down menu full of options?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you create the column as a metadata column and add all the list entries in as metadata tags you can start typing in the box in the form and it will autocomplete your entry / limit your choices based on what you enter.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the answer. Sadly, I still cannot find the solution. the list I am looking up to is an import from Excel (a database). The column I want to lookup is one of the columns of this list, but I cannot change the column type to metadata (can only change it to single line of text, multiple line of text, choice, number, currency or yes/no). Can you tell me how can I have a column from a database being a metadata column?